# Geometric Progression (semicircle)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

There are five semicircles.

The area of the semicircles form a geometric progression. Given that area of the smallest semicircle is $\frac{1}{16}$ of the area of the largest semicircle. If the total area of the semicircles is 30cm^2. Find the area of the smallest and the largest semicircle.

I found this question hard. I've been figuring it some time but still couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Let the area of the $5$ semicircles be respectively in increasing order be $\frac{a}{r^2}$,$\frac{a}{r}$,$a$,$ar$ and $ar^2$.

By the conditions given, we have that $$\frac{a}{r^2}=\frac{1}{16}\cdot ar^2 \Rightarrow r=2$$ since area and thus $r$ cannot be negative

AND $$\frac{a}{r^2}+\frac{a}{r}+a+ar+ar^2=30$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{a}{r^2}\cdot \frac{r^5-1}{r-1}=30 $$
$$\Rightarrow a=\frac{30 \times 4}{31}$$

The result follows.

Comment: The answer is 10 and 160. I couldn't get it

Comment: I this the question has typo

Comment: Surely, me too. Can you check if my answer has any complications or mathematical mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

First, do you see that the fact that these are "areas of semi-circles" is largely irrelevant?  This is a sequence of numbers, in geometric progression such that the "last" (we are not told how many?) is 16 times the first and their sum is 30.  A geometric progression is of the form a, ar, ar^2,  ar^3, ... ar^n for some integer n.  Saying that the last is 16 times larger than the first means that ar^n= 16a.  Dividing both sides by a, r^n= 16.  This single equation is NOT enough to determine both r and n but we certainly can notice that 16= 2^4 so one possible solution is r= 2, n= 4.  It is also true that 16= 4^2 so another possible solution is r= 4, n= 2.

Now, with r= 2, n= 4, and for **any** a, the geometric progression is a, 2a, 4a, 8a, 16a.  The sum of that is a+ 2a+ 4a+ 8a+ 16a= a(1+ 2+ 4+ 8+ 16)= 31a so the condition that the sum be 30 means that 31a= 30 so a= 30/31.
The geometric progression is 30/31, 60/31, 120/31, 240/31, 480/31.   The last term is (480/31)/(30/31)= 480/30= 16, as required, and the sum is 30/31+ 120/31+ 240/31+ 480/31= (30+ 120+ 240+ 480)/31= 930/31= 30, satisfying the conditions.

But with r= 4, n= 2, and, again, any a, the geometric progression is a, 4a, 16a which has sum a+ 4a+ 16a= 21a= 30 so that a= 30/21= 10/7.
The geometric sequence now is 10/7, 40/7, 160/7.  The last term, 160/7 is, in fact, 16 times the first term, 10/7.  And the sum is 10/7+ 40/7+ 160/7= (10+ 40+ 160)/7= 210/7= 30.  This also satisfies the conditions.

Those are, I think, the only solutions such that r and n are integers but there are an infinite number of real number solutions of r^n= 16, any of which will give a sequence satisfying the conditions.  The second solution, with the smallest semi-circle having area 10/7 and the largest 160/7 is probably the solution intended.

Answer (score 0):

We have this information:
\begin{align}
A_k &= a\, q^{k-1} \quad (q > 0, k \in I = \{1,2,3,4,5\}) \\
A_1 &= (1/16) A_5 \\
30 &= \sum_{i\in I} A_i
\end{align}
So
$$
16 a = a q^4 \iff 16 = q^4 \Rightarrow q = 2
$$
This gives
$$
30 = a \sum_{i=0}^4 2^i = a \frac{2^5 - 1}{2 - 1} = 31 a
$$
which gives $a = 30/31$. So we get
$$
A_1 = \frac{30}{31} \quad A_5 = \frac{30}{31} 16 = \frac{480}{31}
$$